# Control/Close 3rd party applications in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have a situation where I have to close other running/suspended applications in iOS, from my application. Is there a way to achieve this in iOS 8.

Initial impression is that I have to increase the memory usage of my app so that iOS closes out other running/suspended applications, but is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm confused why you are insisting your app should be the only one running on the device.  That sounds very hostile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this would be possible to shut apps down from within your own app and if it was I believe Apple would reject your App under the App Store Review Guideline **2.6**

> **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

I believe it will get rejected under this because it will have to read and/or write data outside of the Apps designated container area which isn't allowed. Apps work in a sandboxed mode so they aren't aware of any other Apps running on the device and can't (Not Jailbroken) interact with them except for using URL Schemes.

As for the idea of upping your App memory usage until it starts shutting other apps down idea probably say that your App will also fall at risk of crashing if the memory gets too high which would result in it not being very friendly for users and I believe Apple would actually reject this as well. I can't figure out exactly which rule in the guidelines they would reject it for if they found your App doing this but if it was to crash because of the high memory usage they'd certainly reject it under **2.1** and **2.2**:

> **2.1** Apps that crash will be rejected
>
> **2.2** Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

So I'm sorry to say I don't believe there is any good way to do this that would still allow your App into the Apple App Store.